# Javascript diplaying xml in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am trying to display my xml in a table with an array once the user clicks on an icon. I am not sure how to go about doing it but this is the code I have so far.

```
           $(function(links) {
             $(".link").click(function() {

                 var xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("http://localhost/HTML5/images.xml");
                 function loadXMLDoc(dname) {
                 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
              }
                else {
                    xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
             }
          xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
          xhttp.send();
          return xhttp.responseXML;
              }


              var linkArray = new Array();
              linkArray[0] = "1";
              var counter = $('#noOfLinks').val();
              $('#myTable').append('<table>,<tbody>');
                  for (i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
                     $('#myTable').append('<tr><td><a href=' + linkArray[i] + '>' + textArray[i] + '</a></td></tr>');
               counter++;
              }
              $('#myTable').append('</tbody>,</table>');

             });
          });
```

This is my xml

```
     <links>
  <link>
    <hyperlink>http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1641349/</hyperlink>
    <sitename>IMBD</sitename>
    <linkalt>Terra Nova</linkalt>
   </link>
   <link>
    <hyperlink>http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terra_Nova_(TV_series)</hyperlink>
    <sitename>WIKIPEDIA</sitename>
    <linkalt>Terra Nova</linkalt>
   </link>  
   </links>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this greatly by using jQuery AJAX

```js
 $.get('/path/to/xml/file/', function(data) {
    /* data is full xml response, wrap in `$()` to use jQuery traverse methods*/
    $(data).find('link').each(function() {
      var name = $(this).find('sitename').text();
      var link = $(this).find('hyperlink').text();

      var row = '<tr><td><a href="' + link + '">' + name + '</a></td></tr>';
      $('#myTable').append(row)

    })
  }, 'xml');
```

Output is simplified for demo purposes

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/6c6Vq8bfxT4yVsXdiWJ0?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: This worked for me but once i click the button again it keeps the links but adds them again. How can I make it so it doesnt duplicate the links?

Comment: call `$('#myTable').empty()` prior to parsing the xml. If need new url from link, is easy to get using `attr()`

Comment: in my demo...can open `data.xml` , paste in new xml you are using and clcik `fork` . Will save new version of demo. What you are saying doesn't make sense unless xml structure changed. Can see from my example, number of links is irelevant to the code processing

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. Thanks. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
xml = $.parseXML(xml); 
var txt = "";
$(xml).find("link").each(function(){
    var href = $(this).find("hyperlink").text();
    var link = $(this).find("sitename").text();
    var alt = $(this).find("linkalt").text();
    txt += "<tr><td><a title='"+alt+"' href='"+href+"'>"+link+"</a></td></tr>";
});
$("table").append(txt);
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/CLAc8/)

Answer (score 0):

```
...
        var table = $('<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered"></table>');
        var thead = $('<tr><th class="text-center">HyperLink</th><th class="text-center">Site</th><th class="text-center">LnkAlt</th></tr>');
        var trow = $('<tr><td class="text-center"></td><td class="text-left"></td><td class="text-left"></td></tr>');
        table.append(thead);
        $(xml).find('link').each(function () {
            $('td', trow).eq(0).html($(this).find('hyperlink').text());
            $('td', trow).eq(1).html($(this).find('sitename').text());
            $('td', trow).eq(2).html($(this).find('linkalt').text());
            table.append(trow);
            trow = $('tr:last-child', table).clone(false);
        });

...
```